# multiple return without global variables

Tags: java, oop, return

Maybe this theory is missing in my programming education, but in object oriented languages, is it possible to construct a method that is able to `return` two or more variables instead of just one.

E.g. I really like `Matlab`'s way of handling this:      `[var1, var2] = myFunction(input);`

Where if I for example only need `var1`, I can do:

`[var1, ~] = myFunction(input);`

Hence discarding the variable I don't need (at that particular instance).

Due to large data-shifts in my actual implementation, I don't want to store the return variables globally, just call the same function over and over again, but receiving the specified (needed) values for that instance.

I thought of the following approach of doing so but I was wondering if there's a better way.

```
public static Double myFunction(Double input, Integer method)
{
    double calcOne   = input*5;
    double calcTwo   = input*25;
    double calcThree = input*300;

    switch(method)
    {
      case 1:  return calcOne;

      case 2:  return calcTwo;

      case 3:  return calcThree;

      default: return calcOne;
    } 
}
```

Note that I clearly need the seperation between the `return` statements and the calculations (calculations in real program involves a large `for loop` and reading from files etc.)

### Edit

The reason why I don't use 3 different methods is because I use a very large `for loop` in my method. My main method then sometimes needs one `return` variable from this method and sometimes two.

Therefore the following might be a (better) solution:

```
public static ArrayList<Double> myFunction(double input, int[] method)
{
    double calcOne   = input*5;
    double calcTwo   = input*25;

    ArrayList<Double> returnValues = new ArrayList<Double>();

    if (Arrays.asList(method).contains(1))
    {
        returnValues.add(calcOne);
    }
    if (Arrays.asList(method).contains(2))
    {
        returnValues.add(calcTwo);
    }

    return returnValues;
}
```

where `int[] method` contains the variable 'names' the function should return.

Comment: I you want to return more than one variable, why don't you return an object with those variables or an array?

Comment: @morgano: Because I don't need ALL return variables everytime I call the function (I call it multiple times). Returning an object means storing the object in the main thread as well, including storing all the (unneccesary) otherwise temporary variables. Isn't it better to deal with this problem within the method?

Comment: @morgano: considering the fact my actual return variables are of huge sizes, putting them in an array and then only extracting the relevant entry seems redundant.

Comment: A return Value is *always* a single ... "object". However, that Object can be ANYTHING. You can return a single value like `return 1` - or you could return a List, a class, a List of Lists of Maps of String and class - or whatever you require.

Comment: @dognose: I get that. But it doesn't make sense to return let's say an array of 3 huge strings if I only need 1 specific string at that line of code.

Comment: In that case what you need is every value to be calculated for a single method each, and just call the methods for the needed values. Maybe we're missing something you haven't told us, why do you need to calculate different return values in a same method?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with whether the language is object-oriented or partly object-oriented or not.  A syntax like this could have been added to Java without making it any less object-oriented.  Defining how it would work and all the rules for it would be difficult, especially since it's a strongly-typed compiled language.    It has nothing to do with OOP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a been using a very basic approach to deal with problems of multiple returns. It serves the purpose, and avoids complexity.

I call it the **string separator** Approach

And it is effective as it can even return values of **Multiple Types** e.g. int,double,char,string etc

In this approach we make a use of a string that is very unlikely to occur generally.
We call it as a separator.
This separator would be used to separate various values when used in a function

For example we will have our final return as (for example) intValue separator doubleValue separator...
And Then  using this string we will retrieve all the information required, that can be of diffrent types as well

Following code will Show the working of this concept

The separator used is **!@#** and
 3 values are being returned intVal,doubleVal and stringVal

```
        public class TestMultipleReturns {

            public static String multipleVals() {

                String result = "";
                String separator = "!@#";


                int intVal = 5;
                // Code to process intVal

                double doubleVal = 3.14;
                // Code to process doubleVal

                String stringVal = "hello";
                // Code to process Int intVal

                result = intVal + separator + doubleVal + separator + stringVal + separator;
                return (result);
            }

            public static void main(String[] args) {

                String res = multipleVals();

                int intVal = Integer.parseInt(res.split("!@#")[0]);
                // Code to process intVal

                double doubleVal = Double.parseDouble(res.split("!@#")[1]);
                // Code to process doubleVal

                String stringVal = res.split("!@#")[2];

                System.out.println(intVal+"\n"+doubleVal+"\n"+stringVal);
            }
        }
```

OUTPUT

```
5
3.14
hello
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Comment: I must say this is pretty genius! Very creative solution!

Comment: Disadvantage however is that I still need to cast the different data types. But it remains a very creative solution!

Comment: I mostly use the Separator Approach in other places as well... Mostly to pass information from one end to another having constraint of only using Strings

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know it is not possible to return multiple variables in one return statement. 
However you can define a call such that:

```
public ClassA {
      public String var1;
      public int var2;
      public char var3;
      public Long var4;
}
```

then populate the object and return it. Inside the object you can store as many variables as necessary and return them all via one object.

Comment: But calling the object means all variables get saved. In my implementation above, only the relevant variable is (permanently) saved and the others are discarded.

Comment: No problem, save only those that you need. Everything else either don't store into the object or make them equals to null if you don't need them. Garbage collector will free the memory for you.

Comment: @Melr: But how can I store different variables if the function remains the same?

Comment: Sure you can, why not? Care to give example?

Comment: @Melr: I don't get it. The function populates the variables (var1, var2, var3, var4). If the function remains the same, how can two calls to the function result in different populations?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible.  Sort of.

In Java, you can do it by returning an array of objects, or by creating and returning an instance of a light-weight class that has fields to hold the multiple values you want to return.  The caller then has to pull the values out of the array or object.

In other OO (and non-OO) languages, there is more direct support; e.g. in some languages (Python, Ruby, Perl, etc), you can do something like this:

```
  [a, b, c] = someMethodReturningATuple()
```

The syntax on the LHS assigns values to variables `a`, `b` and `c`.

Java doesn't support this, but that is partly because it doesn't have a built-in tuple type, or an "array of anything" type.  And without one of those it would be difficult to shoe-horn this into the language.  (And a hypothetical "array of anything" type probably wouldn't cut, it because that would rely on dynamic typing at the caller end.)

---

Note that this nothing to do with OO versus non-OO ... or even statically typed versus dynamically typed languages.  (I first used multi-return in the Mesa language in the 1980's.  Mesa was statically typed.)  It is more to do with the set of linguistic features that the respective language designers thought needed to be supported.

Comment: but still this (using an array object) forces me to store the variables outside of the method. I'd rather deal with the return statements inside of the method to be sure the redundant variables are temporary and get discarded.

Comment: @Jean-Paul - variables don't get discarded.  Values do.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, only a single Object can be returned by a `return` function. The alternate methods (besides global variables) for returning multiple values are as follows:

1. Use an Array

   ```
   Object [] myarray = new Object [length];
   ```

Since `Object` is a superclass for most of the variables you might want to store, an array of objects can be a good way to return multiple values and only use the ones you need.

One of the drawbacks of using this array is that it stores Objects and not a more specific data type (e.g. `String`) which has its own special set of operations. This requires a typecast or other conversion to use specific `String` operations.

If all your return values are of the same data type, then it is much easier to create an array of that single data type and avoid this limitation:

```
  String [] mystrings = new String [length];
```

1. Use a `List`

This option works much like an array, but lists have some additional flexibility. A list is created like this:

```
  List<Object> mylist = new LinkedList<Object>();
```

An items are added like this:

```
  mylist.add(myVar);
```

Like an array, if all your data values are of the same type, this method avoids the limitations discussed above.

1. Create an Object

You can declare a class with multiple parameters. These parameters have specific data types, so they can use all the built-in Java libraries for their data type without a typecast or conversion. This avoids the main drawback of an `Array` or `List` of Objects.

```
    public ReturnObject () {
         public int param1;
         public String myString;
    }
```

As all these options work because they return a single Object, but several data values are returned within that object.

Answer (score 1):

`E.g. I really like Matlab's way of handling this: [var1, var2] = myFunction(input);`

Please never ever consider "Matlab" a programming language :P

The Equivalent of what you are looking for would be something like :

```
List<Double> result = doSomething(5);
System.out.println(result.get(0)); // 25

public List<Double> doStomething(Integer input){
   List<Double> result= new LinkedList<Double>();

   Double calcOne = input*5;
   Double calcTwo = input*25;

   result.add(calcOne);
   result.add(calcTwo);
   return result;
}
```

However ALL values are caluclated, even if you just want to use "First result". If you only need ONE of the results - create 3 Methods and call, what you need, like:

```
public Double calcOne(Integer input){
   ...
}

public Double calcTwo(Integer input){
   ...
}

public Double calcThree(Integer input){
   ...
}
```

Comment: Do you consider Perl a programming language? :) :)

Comment: haha ok I will use `numerical computing environment` then. The multiple method solution is trivial, but not my question.

Comment: @Jean-Paul You also could use one mehtod with different return values ofc. But assuming, your calculations always depend on the input and are not as trivial as `x*y` - Why not use seperate methods?

Comment: @ajb Not answering this :) Can't handle downvotes :P

Comment: @dognose: see edit to question. Maybe making two seperate methods to accomodate the different implementations is the best solution after all. With many variables, it becomes a tedious process though.

Comment: @Jean-Paul I think there is no "wrong" or "right" solution. It depends on your needs and personal preference. If you need your method to be able to handle 1 upto n return values - ONE parameterized method is the way to go. (Nobody wants to write 785 methods to return upto 785 results). If its more like a ranking, where you frequently need to pull 1-3rd place, mehtods like `getFirst(); getSecond(); getThird()` are handy as well. "Basically" you could write a whole app with ONE method - Or you can split every "character" printed in a seperate method - its up to you! :)

Comment: @dognose: Yeah I totally agree. I like the `temporary variable` feature in methods a lot so I will try to use my initial intuition and just pass another variable to the method indicating which variable to return. That way I'm sure I won't waste any redundant memory.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea is to create a class that uses a "hashmap" type to store the values ​​of the parameters. This class exposes methods for example to add parameter and value, to find a value for a parameter, remove a parameter, to obtain the number of parameters, etc. .. The important thing is to hide the use of the data type to store the information. In the event you would like to change the "hashmap" type by something else, the client of your class would not be affected WHILE you do not change the public interface of your class

***Exemple***

```
public class Context {

private HashMap<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<String, Object>();

// Get value for parameter name
public Object getAttribute(String name) {
    return attributes.get(name);
}

// Set value for parameter name
public void setAttributes(String name, Object value) {
    removeAttributes(name);
    attributes.put(name, value);
}

// Returns the number of values 
public int getSize() {
    return this.attributes.size();
}

// remove parameter
public void removeAttributes(String name) {
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Object>> iter = this.attributes.entrySet().iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String, Object> entry = iter.next();
        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(entry.getKey())) {
            iter.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**The disadvantage** with this solution is that you must convert (**cast**) the object to obtain the original value. If you have only one type of data is not so bad. By cons, if you want to store several diferent types it can become complicated. but, it's a idea !!!!

```
@Test
public void testContext() {

    // Le context
    Context context = new Context();

    Integer param1 = new Integer(1);
    BigDecimal param2 = new BigDecimal(19700101);
    String param3 = new String("hello world");

    // Add 3 parameters (key, value)
    context.setAttributes("param_1", param1);
    context.setAttributes("param_2", param2);
    context.setAttributes("param_3", param3);
    Assert.assertEquals(3, context.getSize()); // test the number of key-value mappings in this map.

    Integer resultParam1 = (Integer) context.getAttribute("param_1");
    BigDecimal resultParam2 = (BigDecimal) context.getAttribute("param_2");
    String resultParam3 = (String) context.getAttribute("param_3");

    Assert.assertEquals(param1, resultParam1);
    Assert.assertEquals(param2, resultParam2);  
    Assert.assertEquals(param3, resultParam3);  

    // remove parameter
    context.removeAttributes("param_1");
    Assert.assertEquals(2, context.getSize());  // 3add - 1remove = 2 parameters

    // Replace value parameter by another value
    Long value = new Long(1976);
    context.setAttributes("param_2", value);

    // and so on ...
}
```